# how to enable google maps api v2 in the new google console

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have been trying to use `google maps`,it always shows blank, I've tried all the method it is not working I was wondering about the `android api v2`, so I went to console and `enabled Maps SDK` for android, it still did'nt worked( I have disabled the applicaton restriction means didn't used SSH1 certificate or package name).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to this site [Google's Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) then create or select an Project.
After that click on Enable API's and Services after you have selected the Project you created or Project you selected. Then select Maps SDK for Android and after redirecting you will see an option of Enable.